# Any great tutorials on hosting a Laravel API on Azure? Or does anyone know how to on here?

Tags: laravel, azure, laravel-5

I am getting the run around on the net and would like to know if anyone has found a great walk through for deploying a Laravel API to Azure?

Comment: The one answer currently hosted on here is about 3 years old if I am not mistaken and as all of you know Azure changes quite frequently!

Comment: try [here](https://medium.com/@ophasnoname_44358/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-5-4-php-application-to-microsoft-azure-webapp-service-9f951a8d964e) and [here](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-azure-web-app-b55e12514c46)

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer directly your question and you may not be using/paying for forge...

But, if you use Laravel Forge. you can follow this set up and forge will do most of the deployment for you. Most of it...

https://medium.com/@piesse/laravel-forge-on-azure-d429a6cba6d4

if you never used forge, i would certainly recommend to pay at least the first month just to see what it is and to make your deployment easier. i hope this is not seen as spam, since im not trying to sell a product, im recommending a way for your deployment to be done.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!